# Setting view in NSSplitView not working

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, nssplitview

Please excuse my ignorance, I'm coming from iOS to Mac programming. I have two nibs. One is the main window with the split view. The nib contains a navigationController view I created. I'm trying to replace the right pane of the split view (navigationView) with this view. When the application first launches, navigationView is just a custom view in interface builder.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc]
                                           initWithNibName:@"NavigationController" 
                                           bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    navigationView = navController.view;
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. I tried adding the navController.view as a subview, and that at least gets it showing up, but it is placed very oddly. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely have to add the views you want in the NSSplitView as a subviews of the NSSplitView. You'll need to provide more information about what happens after that.

There's lots of sample code on Apple's website and many of them use NSSplitViews.

Comment: Further comment, check out this particular sample code : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html especially childnode / basenode code.